# How can i sort months in Power BI when get data from direct server?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have a direct connection to analytics services. I saw that it is easy to manipulate the data when it is imported, but when I connect directly to the server it cannot do it (at least not intuitively). I need to sort the months in a data segment but there are no options for the data to perform this task. These are currently arranged alphabetically but should be arranged chronologically.

[image]

I saw that it is easy to manipulate the data when it is imported, but when I connect directly to the server it cannot do it (at least not intuitively)

[image]

Comment: add some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: @mkRabbani done!

Comment: You have only month name in the table? or you have Date values as well. To apply ordering on Month name, you need Date or other value for Ordering data.

Comment: If you are using a *Live Connection* to an Analysis Services model (this is different to a *Direct Connection* to source data), I think your only option is to get the setting changed on the source model.

Answer (score 0):

Based on different scenario discussed in the comments and messaging, I am editing my answer completely and here is the new option using **Custom Column**.

Create a custom column with this below code-

```
created_custom_date = "1-" & month_names[month] & "-2020"
```

**Note:** just adding date and year to the Month name to create a well formatted Date.

Now change the data type of this column as DateTime and you will get a "Date Hierarchy" option under that column. use Month value from the "Date Hierarchy" in the chart. you should now get proper ordering in your chart as shown in the below image-

[image]

Comment: Will this work with a Live Connection to Analysis Services?  As far as I am aware this is a model setting, which in this case is held within the Analysis Services instance and not the dashboard

Comment: you have to do it in power query editor. After you imported your data to power bi.

Comment: Well yes, as I say that option isn't available if you are using a Live Connection to an Analysis Services model, as the model is defined and held in Analysis Services, not in the Power BI File.

Comment: Yup, got it. You can create a measure like- Return 1 when January, 2 when February.... 12 for December. Then try to order by that measure.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't order by a measure either

Comment: You can, but that has to be a part of the visual :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220371/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-iamdave).

Comment: So it would not be possible to perform this task using power bi tools? in that case, it would have to be done manually in the database using a nomenclature like this (January 1-, February 2-, ..) and there if they would be ordered. It is the easiest solution that I can think of considering that the data cannot be manipulated in the direct connection

Comment: @Lucho, this is possible. I will update my answer soon.